# How to disable popup menu items like Select, Select All, Suggest..., Define (on UIWebView)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiapplication, uiresponder

How to disable popup menu items like **Select**, **Select All**, **Suggest...**, **Define** (on `UIWebView`)?

I have found the following information on the help but don't understand how to use it:

> For the editing menu commands, this is the shared **UIApplication**
>   object. Depending on the context, you can query the sender for
>   information to help you determine whether a command should be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swizzle the following method:

```
#import "NSObject+myCanPerformAction.h"

@implementation NSObject (myCanPerformAction)

- (BOOL)myCanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return [self myCanPerformAction:action withSender:sender]; // not a recursion
    }
    if (action == @selector(paste:)) {
        return [self myCanPerformAction:action withSender:sender]; // not a recursion
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Swizzling:

```
[[UIWebDocumentView class] jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(canPerformAction:withSender:) withMethod:@selector(myCanPerformAction:withSender:) error:nil];
```

Comment: It really works for all copy,paste,etc. but still in pop up, it's showing "replace" action .Now how to hide that one.