# How to replace method of UIWebView instead restricted subclassing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, subclassing

Subclassing of UIWebView is restricted by Apple. But I need to replace method `canPerformAction` to the following one:

```
-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if ((action == @selector(Copy:)) || (action == @selector(Paste:))) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

How to replace this method without subclassing? Thank you a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace a function in a class you can use method swizzling. There's a nice library that does everything for you called [JRSwizzle](http://cocoaobjects.com/jrswizzle/).

```
[[UIWebView class] jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(canPerformAction:withSender:) withMethod:@selector(myCanPerformAction:withSender:) error:nil];
```

The all you need to do is to create a category on UIWebView that implements `myCanPerformAction:withSender:`

```
-(BOOL) myCanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if ((action == @selector(Copy:)) || (action == @selector(Paste:))) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is good practice though...

Comment: Replaced method works perfectly but nasty items on a popup menu of `UIWebView` still exist :(( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233613/how-to-disable-popup-menu-items-like-select-select-all-suggest-define-on

Comment: It sounds strange but if you call your function inside your function it'll actually call the replaced one...

Comment: Method A was replaced by method B. Now I want to call A inside B. How to do it?

Comment: `-(void) B { [self B]; }` It looks like it'll cause a loop but when you call B from inside B it actually calls A.

Comment: But do you know how to fix it?